# React CSSTransitionGroup not transitioning smoothly

Tags: reactjs, animation, transition, reactcsstransitiongroup

> Hi, I am trying to use React's CSSTransitionGroup to smoothly fade in
>   a spinner for loading during an async call once a button is clicked,
>   but even when I do everything according to the documentation (https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable), the
>   transition does not happen smoothly.
>
> To describe what is actually
>   happening more clearly, when the button is clicked:
>
> 1. The button is "pushed down" by the length of the spinner on the page.
> 2. At this point, the html is a div containing the spinner (with enter attributes) and the button underneath it (with leave attributes)
> 3. The button fades out in what appears to be half a second. Once it has faded out, the spinner fades in.
> 4. After a few seconds, the entire transition seems to have finished, and only the button exists (with correct spacing).
>
> ### Code
>
> ```
>  // App.js
>  import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
>
>  export default class App extends Component {
>      constructor(props) {
>           super(props);
>           this.renderButton = this.renderButton.bind(this);
>      }
>
>      renderButton(handleClick, fetching, fetched) {
>           if (!fetching && !fetched) {
>               return(<button className="async-btn" key="async-btn" type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Start Async</button>);
>           }
>           else {
>                return(<Spinner key="spinner" />);
>           }
>       }
>
>       render() {
>       const { fetched, fetching, handleClick } = this.props;
>           return (
>               <CSSTransitionGroup
>               transitionName="fade"
>               transitionEnterTimeout={500}
>               transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
>                   {this.renderButton(handleClick, fetching, fetched)}
>               </CSSTransitionGroup>
>           )
>       }
> }
>
> // index.css
> .fade-enter {
>   opacity: 0.01;
> }
>
> .fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
>   opacity: 1;
>   transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
> }
>
> .fade-leave {
>   opacity: 1;
> }
>
> .fade-leave.fade-leave-active {
>   opacity: 0.01;
>   transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
> }
> ```
>
> ### Questions
>
> 1) Can I NOT trigger successful transitions like I am doing with
>   switching in between a button and component (which is simply a div
>   with a img within it)? Or must it be a ul or array rendering?
>
> 2) Is there anything else that I am not following according to
>   documentation?
>
> Thank you.

Comment: I dont see any problem... there have to apper both elements during the transition. If you dont want to trigger transition so why you put it into transition?

Comment: I apologize if this was not clear (what I am seeing is hard to describe). I want a transition, but the transition is not smooth at all. In fact, the transition looks like it's jumping down contrary to what I would think it looks like. Unless, is there a specific characteristic that I need to give in order to simply fade out and fade in using CSSTransitionGroups?

Comment: maybe you are missing positioning? It means you for example put `position: absolute` into .fade-leave class so it will be fading out like layer above.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to fade in/out between two different elements seamlessly requires the container to be position: relative, with the element within the container having position: absolute.

Credit to Melounek for his helpful thought in the comments above.

This stackoverflow post is comprehensive and lays out the solution well: [React animate transition between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426539/react-animate-transition-between-components)